# Is an algebraic formula to test real numbers equality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a formula to test numbers equality ?

Let $x$ and $y$ real numbers. If $x=y$ the formula will results $1$. Else the formula will results $0$.

I'm not searching for an algorithmic solution but a algebraic solution.

**EDIT** : To be more precise, I would say that I'm looking for a solution in the form of a function.

*Example :* I need a function that returns $42$ if you give it $1$, but returns $13$ if given $0$. That function is
$f(x)=29*x+13$.

Here I'm searching a function with two variables, that returns $1$ if the two variables are equal, and returns $0$ if the two variables are not equal.

Comment: What do you deem to be'an algebraic solution'? Is the kronecker delta function good enough? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta

Comment: What do you mean by an "algebraic formula"?  I ask because many would regard "$x = y$" as an algebraic formula which tests for equality!

Comment: That depends on what exactly you mean by "algebraic". $e^{-10^{10^{10^{100000}}}(x-y)^2}$ is good for all practical purposes you can think of and $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n(x-y)^2}$ is both formally correct and useful. On the other hand, since any elementary algebraic formula defines a continuous function on its domain and the function you want is discontinuous, the formal answer is "No".

Comment: $1-sign(|x-y|)$ where $sign(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}$ if $x\not=0$ and $sign(0)=0$.

Comment: @metacompactness That should be an answer :)

Comment: Perfect answer !

Comment: There is nothing useful that doesn't basically repeat your "if $\dots$ then $\dots$ else $\dots$" specification.

Comment: Is the formula going to be implemented in a computer program? If it is, then the counter-arguments based on continuity don't apply, and you can get what you want (even without using the sign function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$1-sign(|x-y|)$ where $sign(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}$ if $x\not=0$ and $sign(0)=0$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect anwser.

Comment: Wait, I just realized, doesn't $\operatorname{sign}(|x-y|)$ become $\frac{0}{0}$ when $x=y$?

Comment: The sign function is certainly not continuous.  Maybe you meant to say that it's defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @JesseMadnick You're right.